# php loop through json array

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, foreach

I have a json string like this:

```
$fields_string = '
{"fields":
   {"customers":[{"name":"john","id":"d1"},
                 {"name":"mike","id":"d2"},
                 {"name":"andrew","id":"d3"},
                 {"name":"peter","id":"d4"}]
   }
}'
```

How can I print each name? I will use them later in a html select options, I know how to do that. But I couldn't get the string out. 
Here are something I tried:

```
$obj = json_decode($fields_string);
$fields_detail = $obj-?{"fields"}->{"customers"};
```

at this point, I am able to print the customer array out by `echo json_encode($fields_detail)`, but before that, I want to get the name break down using `foreach`. I tried several times, it didn't work. Can anyone help please.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to get what? How did you try? How did it not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Customers is an array of objects so iterating over each object and reading the property should work.

```
foreach ($fields_detail as $customer) {
  echo $customer->name;
}
```

Comment: @koopajah you missed the second fragment of code http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/xr4-8tz

Comment: I see what I have done wrong. This is just it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
$data = json_decode($fields_string, true); // return array not object
foreach($data['fields']['customers'] as $key => $customer) {
 echo $customer['name']; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Access the names via `fields->customers`:

```
$obj = json_decode($fields_string);

foreach($obj->fields->customers as $customer)
{
    echo $customer->name . "\n";
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/xWaARRjV)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($obj->fields->customers as $fields)
echo $fields->name;
```